# What do the brackets after a declaration of a vector object mean?

Tags: c++, oop

I come from a Python background, but I was reading up on the kind of objects and data structures available in the C++ standard library and I see that the declaration for say, a `vector` of strings:

```
vector<string> names(10);
```

Would indicate a `vector` object initialized to hold 10 objects of type `string`. My questions are:

- Does the `<string>` part of the declaration have an abstraction to C++ class system, i.e. is it a in built syntax for the vector object or part of some feature of the class system that can be used on user-defined class definitions?
- Am I right in assuming that the brackets followed by the name are the arguments passed to the constructor function?
- Is `string` a built-in type like `int` or an object defined by the standard library. And thus, is there a difference between built-in types and other objects (for instance all "types" are objects in Python)?

Comment: 1. Look up templates. 2. Yes. 3. It's a premade class, not a built-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sorts of parameters to `std::vector` objects:

1. There template arguments which are for `std::vector` the value type and the allocator types with the latter being defaulted. That is, `std::vector<std::string>` actually happens to be `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >`.
2. There are run-time parameters passed as constructor arguments and `std::vector<...>` takes quite a few combinations of those. In the above quoted use the `10` is the number of initial elements given to the vector.

So, to answer your concrete questions:

1. The `string` happens to be `std::string` and is nothing special at all. You can use any user-defined type which models certain concepts (e.g. the type needs to be `CopyConstructible`).
2. The arguments in the parentheses are the contructor arguments (in the C++ context brackets are normally `[` and `]` but the term is ambiguous).
3. `string`, well, actually `std::string` is not defined as a built-in type but it is a type from the standard C++ library. How the standard C++ library types are implemented is pretty much up to the C++ implementation, however, i.e., an implementation could choose to make it built-in (as long as it can still be used like a class type).

In C++ there are a few differences between built-in types and class types but with C++ 2011 it is gets pretty close to being able to create class types which behave like built-in types. The primary difference is that it is possible to take the address of certain members of class types while the same "members" are not accessible for built-in types. Another difference is that built-in types don't need to be declared (actually, they cannot be declared) while class types need to be declared and/or defined (depending on how these are used).